# problem with variable assignment to arrays using structs in c

Tags: c, struct, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to multiply matrices in c. However when I try to multiply the numbers in the two arrays, and put them in an answer array its always zero. heres the code for the method, thanks.

My matrix struct:

```
typedef struct matrix {
 int r;
 int c;
 double **mat;
 } *matrix_t;
```

My matrix multiplying method:

```
matrix_t mat_mult(matrix_t a, matrix_t b)
{
 int i, j, k;
 double x, temp1, temp2;
 double tempsol = 0.0;
 x = temp1 = temp2 = 0;
 matrix_t answer;

 if(a -> c == b -> r)
 {
    answer = mat_new(a -> r, b -> c);

    for(i = 0; i < a -> r; i++) 
       for( j = 0; j < b -> c; j++)
       {

           for( k = 0; k < a -> c; k++)
           {
               tempsol += a->mat[i][k] * b->mat[k][j];
               answer-> mat[i][j] =  tempsol;
           }

       }

 return answer;
 }
 else if(a -> r == b -> c)
 {
  answer = mat_new(a -> c, b -> r); 
  return answer;
 }
 else
 {
  printf("Matrices could not be multiplied");
  exit(1);
  return;
 }
}
```

heres the code for my mat_new as well

```
matrix_t mat_new(int r,int c)
{
int i = 0;
double **a;
matrix_t matrix_a;  

a = (double**)malloc(r *sizeof(double *));
for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    a[i] = (double*)malloc(c *sizeof(double));
}
matrix_a = (matrix_t) malloc ( sizeof(struct matrix));
matrix_a -> mat = a;
matrix_a -> r = r;
matrix_a -> c = c;

return matrix_a;
}
```

Comment: The code is not properly in the code block. You should edit and correct that one. Besides, just curious, are you allocating memory for  the double **mat correctly ?

Comment: yea, i believe the memory is allocated correctly, it can store values and print them, but for some reason in this method it wont let me multiply numbers from the other two matrices and put it in the "answer" matrix. if i add them it works, but multiplying does nothing.

Comment: I am new to this site, what do you mean by it's not properly in the code block.

Comment: Re: the above: You might find it easier to allocate a linear array of memory instead of allocating all the row pointers (`r * sizeof(double*)`) and then allocating each column (`c * sizeof(double)`), which saves you `r` allocations. Then, to get an element of the array at row `i`, column `j`, access `mat[i * c + j]`, where `c` is the number of columns.

Comment: @jbernie2: Goutham means that it probably wasn't formatted well when you posted it. If you indent your code with four spaces, it gets syntax-highlighting and proper spacing. I see that @wallyk has fixed it up for you.

Comment: What's with the unused variables and crappy indentation? It might not matter to you, but many people won't even read the code that doesn't look OK from far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like all your issues stem from reading in matrix values as integers rather than doubles. Everything works fine if you change temp in read_mat() to an int, then cast it to a double when you're putting it in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `free` your objects. You need to reset `tempsol`. But most importantly, you need to review your `mat_mult()`.

```
matrix_t mat_mult(matrix_t a, matrix_t b)
{
 /* ... */
 if(a -> c == b -> r)
 {
  /* ... */
 }
 else if(a -> r == b -> c)
 {
                                    /* BZZZZT!                 */
  answer = mat_new(a -> c, b -> r); /* BZZZZT! mat_mult(b, a); */
                                    /* BZZZZT!                 */
  return answer;
 }
 else
 {
  /* ... */
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your example:

```
matrix_t mat_new(int r,int c)
{
  matrix_t new = malloc(sizeof*new);
  new->r   = r;
  new->c   = c;
  new->mat = malloc( r*c*sizeof(double) );
  return new;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't contain any obvious errors. Perhaps the problem lies in your mat_new(). The way you defined mat in your matrix structure as `double **mat;`, which I wouldn't recommend, may be causing some problems.

To allocate a 2x2 matrix to mat, you would need to do:

```
mat = new (double*)[2];
mat[0] = new double[2];
mat[1] = new double[2];
```

or a n by m matrix:

```
mat = new (double*)[n];
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
  mat[i] = new double[m];
}
```

Is this what you are doing?

Comment: this is my mat_new method, I dont't use the method you used, but if yours is better, i obviously will, anyways, heres mat_new

Comment: The title was "C". Your solution is C++.